# Build Boost 1.52 Libraries using Visual Studio 2012 to target Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

"Visual Studio 2012 Update 1" enabled support for a Windows XP target using toolset "vc110_xp".

How do I configure Boost 1.52 to build libraries using the vc110_xp toolset ?

Comment: I didn't specify anything, just built them with the regular vc110 toolset. I guess the only thing vc110_xp changes is the OS version in the COFF header.

Comment: It also changes the libraries that are linked as WinXP does not support of the API calls used in new Libraries.

Attempting to link code compiled with vc110_xp and boost libraries compiled with vc110 produced link errors.

Comment: The "targeting from command line" section of this article should help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx

Comment: Boost.Build can forward quite some options to the build system: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties ... maybe some luck there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the easiest way was to edit `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` add lines to change the `LIB`, `INCLUDE`, `PATH` and `CL` variables after the defaults were loaded. Boost.Build uses this batch file so you don't need to make any other changes.

For example here is the new `:x86` section

```
:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"

set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_;%CL%

goto :SetVisualStudioVersion
```

Wth the four `set`'s being the additions. A similar thing can be done for the `:amd64` section, though I'm hesitant to post it as I've only tested XP 32bit myself, I've been happy to target Vista+ for 64bit builds.

Comment: This is basically what did, though I ended up adding another label (:x86_xp) and creating another shortcut window.

Comment: I added the x86_xp lab too but I really don't like this solution.

Comment: @Eoin I would like to follow your suggestion but for VC++ 2013.  Here is my unmodified :x86 section:
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion
Can just paste the 'set' lines above and modify the last line for ..V120_SDK71_; Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran Actually you still use the preprocessor define `_USING_V110_SDK71_` even with VC 2013. But beyond that I no longer have access to an XP machine so cannot test if this method still works.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of the below files in boost folder( which is downloaded and extracted)

Folder :  boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\tools

Files:

1. msvc.jam

content changed :

```
for 32 bit :
          toolset.flags msvc LINKFLAGS <user-interface>console : /subsystem:console,5.01 ;

for 64 bit:
          toolset.flags msvc LINKFLAGS <user-interface>console : /subsystem:console,5.02 ;
```

1. msvc.py

content changed :

```
for 32 bit :
          toolset.flags('msvc', 'LINKFLAGS', ['<user-interface>console'], ['/subsystem:console,5.01'])

for 64 bit:
          toolset.flags('msvc', 'LINKFLAGS', ['<user-interface>console'], ['/subsystem:console,5.02'])
```

Folder :  boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\engine

Files:

1. build.bat

content changed :

```
    for 32 bit/ 64 bit :
       1.   fix the Visual Studio Path Exactly like instead of "%ProgramFiles%- change
               to  %ProgramFiles(x86)%

       2.   Add " /D _USING_V110_SDK71_ " to BOOST_JAM_CC =cl command before Skip_VC11
```

Open vs2012 developer Command prompt and type the following commands

** update 7.1A SDK path as per your installation

1. call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
2. set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
3. set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
4. set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
5. bootstrap
6. Pick the command as per the OS Type (32/64 bit)

   for 32 bit :

   b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared runtime-link=shared address-model=32

   for 64 bit :

   b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared runtime-link=shared address-model=64

To compile any sample for release and debug versions follow this:

Open vs2012 developer Command prompt and type the following commands

1. call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
2. set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
3. set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
4. set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
5. go to the directory of the sample : ex: boost_1_54_0\libs\test\tools\console_test_runner
6. type the following command

   ```
   <path>\boost_1_54_0\bjam.exe --v2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared
   ```