# Boost 1.53.0 - LNK1104 Error when building VC++11

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, linker

I am attempting to build boost v. 1.53 for the first time and am getting this error message:

Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'   C:\Users\ryant_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Phase 2\Phase 2\LINK   Phase 2

I have C:....\boost_1_53_0  in my include directories and
C:...\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib on my additional dependencies on the linker menu.

What file am I missing to link in I can't find it after scouring the documentation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe a bit redundant question but I want to make this very clear: You get the linker error while building the boost libraries? Not your production code (using boost libs)?

Comment: Assumed that the answer is yes: Have you checked if the file is actually there (in the appropriate directory)? Have you followed the build instructions provided at boost.org?

Comment: Do you have `libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib` file in `C:...\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872111/build-boost-1-52-libraries-using-visual-studio-2012-to-target-windows-xp/19004616#19004616

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all it's loveliness and claims of being a header-only collection, boost does have some parts that need to be built into libraries in order for you to use them.  One of these libraries is `date_time`.  Boost is friendly in the sense that it will automatically link the correct `.lib` file for you when you `#include` a library, based on your compiler options.  The caveat is that you need to have built the libraries first.

The file you're missing is `libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib`, which we can see from the [naming convention](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) is the multi-threaded, debug version, using the debug runtimes, for VC11 (that's Visual C++ 2012 to you and I).  It's possible that you simply haven't built that specific version of the libraries - boost by default performs a *minimal* build, skipping several versions of the libraries.  Although it takes a bit of time, I find it's good to build *everything* in boost... hey, hard drive space is cheap!

Open up a Visual Studio command prompt, and make your way to the boost directory:

```
C:\> cd boost_1_53_0
C:\boost_1_53_0\> bootstrap.bat vc11
C:\boost_1_53_0\> .\b2 --build-type=complete toolset=vc11
... now go and make yourself a cup of tea
```

It will take some time, but it should build all combinations of every library.  You can speed it up a little on a multi-core machine by adding, for example, `-j4` to the `.\b2` command line, which will build four things at a time.

The `vc11` part defines the toolset to be used, which is handy if you have two compilers - in theory it shouldn't be necessary (boost does a good job of finding the correct toolset), but it doesn't hurt to make sure.

If you want to test that this is the issue, then you can specify to just build all combinations of the missing date_time library instead:

```
C:\boost_1_53_0\> .\b2 --build-type=complete toolset=vc11 --with-date_time
... now go and make yourself a cold drink, this won't take so long
```

Comment: thanks a lot a lot for your help - when I ran C:\boost_1_53_0\> .\b2 --build-type=complete toolset=msvc11 I got an error saying "msvc11.jam" not found so I just ran it without that toolset option and it did the trick.

Comment: You're right, I think I got the option wrong, and it should also be on the `bootstrap.bat` call - I'll check the parameters and update the answer.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: have you tried building boost as above, but removing the "toolset=vc11" parameter? It _should_ pick the correct one for your environment.

Comment: I have tried it yes. The problem is I have VS2009, VS2010, and VS2012 all installed. I would like boost built for both VS2010 and VS2012 since I have projects using both IDEs.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: You will need to do the above twice, in that case, once for each environment. If you can see both versions from a Visual Studio Command Prompt, then you will need to specify the toolset on the command line: `toolset=vc10` for VS2010, and `toolset=vc11` for VS2012. And hey, why not `toolset=VC9` for VS2008. I had to do this for my system, where I have VS2008, and a Windows SDK which came with VC10.

Comment: Calling b2 with toolset=vc10 produces the error 'vc10.jam: No such file or directory."

Comment: Did you previously run `bootstrap.bat vc10`? That I think creates the vc10.jam file based on the vc10 toolset.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of the below files in boost folder( which is downloaded and extracted)

Folder : boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\tools Files: 1. msvc.jam

content changed :

for 32 bit :
          toolset.flags msvc LINKFLAGS console : /subsystem:console,5.01 ;

for 64 bit:
          toolset.flags msvc LINKFLAGS console : /subsystem:console,5.02 ;

1. msvc.pycontent changed : for 32 bit : toolset.flags('msvc', 'LINKFLAGS', ['console'], ['/subsystem:console,5.01'])

for 64 bit:
          toolset.flags('msvc', 'LINKFLAGS', ['console'], ['/subsystem:console,5.02'])Folder : boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\engine Files: 1. build.bat content changed : for 32 bit/ 64 bit : 1. fix the Visual Studio Path Exactly like instead of "%ProgramFiles%- change to %ProgramFiles(x86)%

```
   2.   Add " /D _USING_V110_SDK71_ " to BOOST_JAM_CC =cl command before Skip_VC11Open vs2012 developer Command prompt and type the following commands
```

** update 7.1A SDK path as per your installation

call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"

set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%

set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%

set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%

bootstrap

Pick the command as per the OS Type (32/64 bit)

for 32 bit :

b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared runtime-link=shared address-model=32

for 64 bit :

b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared runtime-link=shared address-model=64

To compile any sample for release and debug versions follow this:

Open vs2012 developer Command prompt and type the following commands

call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"

set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%

set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%

set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%

go to the directory of the sample : ex: boost_1_54_0\libs\test\tools\console_test_runner

type the following command

\boost_1_54_0\bjam.exe --v2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared